# Uniform discretization of Bezier curve

Tags: path, computational-geometry, spline, bezier

I need to discretise a 3rd order Bezier curve with points equally distributed along the curve. The curve is defined by four points p0, p1, p2, p3 and a generic point p(t) with 0 < t < 1 is given by:

```
point_t = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p0 + 3 * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * t * p1 + 3 * (1 - t) * t * t * p2 + t * t * t * p3;
```

My first idea was to discretise t = 0, t_1, ... t_n, ..., 1

This doesn't work as, in general, we don't end up with a uniform distance between the discretised points.

To sum up, what I need is an algorithm to discretise the parametric curve so that:

```
|| p(t_n) - p(t_n_+_1) || = d
```

I thought about recursively halving the Bezier curve with the [Casteljau algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau's_algorithm) up to required resolution, but this would require a lot of distance calculations.

Any idea on how to solve this problem analytically?

Comment: What you are looking for is also called "arc-length parametrisation". In general, if you subdivide a bezier curve at fixed interval of the "default parametrisation", the resulting curve segments will not have the same arc-length. Here is one way to do it http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing.

Comment: Many thanks @hkrish ! Sampling distance(t) and interpolating is quite an elegant way of solving the problem. I am testing it. Feel free to add this as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Do you mean a constant straight-line (chord) or curvilinear distance ?

Comment: #Yves I mean a curvilinear distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is also called "arc-length parametrisation".

In general, if you subdivide a bezier curve at fixed interval of the *default parametrisation*, the resulting curve segments will not have the same arc-length. Here is one way to do it http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing.

A while ago, I was playing around with a bit of code (curvature flow) that needed the points to be as uniformly separated as possible. Here is a comparison (without proper labeling on axes! ;)) using linear interpolation and [monotone cubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) from the same set of quadrature samples (I used 20 samples per curve, each evaluated using a 24 point gauss-legendre Quadrature) to reparametrise a cubic curve.

[image]

[Please note that, this is compared with another run of the algorithm using a lot more nodes and samples taken as *ground truth*.]

Here is a [demo](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) using monotone cubic interpolation to reparametrise a curve. The function [*Curve.getLength*](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/path/Curve.js#L1392) is the quadrature function.

Comment: do you happen to have a blog post about this up somewhere? I'd love to add cubic interpolation as alternative to linear interpolation to the Primer on Bezier Curves.

Comment: thank you. Is this based on any published article or some other work that can be quoted as source?

Comment: The basic interpolation idea is similar to cubic hermite interpolation. I think, I took the interpolation part from here http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1814-akima-interpolation (BSD licensed). Although we don't need the slope estimation part; here it's Akima's method or like in the wikipedia article where it is Fritsch&Carlson's. We have the slope available directly, so I substituted dt/dl in Akima's method.