# Get points from a curve spline with equal distance each other

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry

I have a spline like this.

```
var spline = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 100), 
    new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 150), 
    new THREE.Vector3(100, 50, 150),
    ...
]); // many many vertices with included interpolations
```

And I need to take points along spline with the same distance between points. I've tried to use **spline.getPoints(100)** and **spline.getSpacedPoints(100)** but it didn't work as I want.

With **getSpacedPoints** I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoSKU.png)
With **getPoints** [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nbvr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10432

*Answered by Mugen87*

> If your curve is large you can try the following: After creating your
>   curve object, set the `__arcLengthDivisions` to a high value:
>
> ```
> curve.__arcLengthDivisions = 1000; // or even higher
> ```
>
> Maybe this will improve the precision of the computation...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/extras/core/Curve.getSpacedPoints), `getSpacedPoints` returns points that are equally distributed along the curve. Of course, the distances kept equal in 3D. So depending on where your camera is rendering from, the points may appear closer that it actually is.. Is that what's happening in your case?

Or you can write your own function. Use this as a base – [Uniform discretization of Bezier curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275073/uniform-discretization-of-bezier-curve/35277050#35277050) (with 2d example, converting to 3D is straightforward.)

Comment: Thanks for answer! In my case I'm getting the different distance between points actually. Another view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCdeQ.png

Comment: Is the distances between points actually different? (using Vector3.distanceTo method?)  Is your curve planar?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. You can check it. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WomOBy (by console)

Comment: I've pushed the question to issues of three.js.

Comment: You can always implement your own btw, like the demo linked.

Comment: I'll try I just haven't hard skills in geometry.